# MOSFET switch not working on PSIM

Tags: voltage, mosfet, switches

I am building a part of a circuit where if the output of a certain comparator is 0, then the MOSFET should be off. However, in this case, it seems that even if the output is 0 (which is being input to the MOSFET on-off switch), the current is able to flow through the MOSFET and a 6V appears at a point where I don't want it to initial output is 0.

[image: What could be wrong here?]

Comment: If you are trying to control the 6V to the line between the 2-input comparator and the AND gate, you should be using a PMOS device.  Right now, you have the gate of the MOSFET referenced to an essentially floating node which will result in undefined operation.

Comment: @vir with an ideal PMOS device, the same issue persists.

Comment: Did you flip it around so the source is connected to the 6V supply?  Also can you put a pull-down resistor on the input to the comparator/AND gate to shunt leakage current to ground?

Comment: What purpose does the MOSFET serve there? Why not just connect the output from the comparator directly to the rest of the circuit?

Comment: In any case, you seem to have a misunderstanding of how a MOSFET works. You want it to switch onwhen the comparator outputs a 'high', but how does the MOSFET 'know' what is 'high' and what is 'low' when it has no 0V ground reference to measure against?

Comment: @brhans I wanted the MOSFET to serve as a switch. Only if the output of the comparator was 1, the voltage at the measured point should be 6V (at least that's my target)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like source of the N-Channel MOSFET is on 6 Volt. You need on gate then a voltage from 6V+5V=11V or possibly 6V+10V=16V. The voltage on the gate must be higher than the voltage on source.

Some little MOSFETS switching on with a gate voltage of only 1.8V. It depends which type of MOSFET you are using!

It would be better if you give your components names, then the people can identify a specific component in your circuit. Even the OPV are not the standard symbol. It is hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: do you mean the 'Diode forward voltage' of the MOSFET has to be 11 or 16? How did you consider the 11 or 16? 
Also, it's just an ordinary MOSFET in PSIM.

Comment: Read a data sheet of a MOSFET or read a page were the standard components are explained. A very good souce is the "Elektronik-Kompendium", but you have to translate the German text to your language. -> https://www.elektronik-kompendium.de/